# C# Not Sure Why Services is null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I am new to WPF application and I am not able to figure out why services.BuildServiceProvider() is null.  I thought once the line where AppHost is declared is executed, ConfigureServices should have built the services object and in turn, _serviceProvider will not be null in the OnStartup method.

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{

    private readonly ServiceProvider \_serviceProvider;

    public static IHost? AppHost { get; private set; }

    public App()
    {
        ServiceCollection services = new();
        AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
            .Build();
        **_serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();**
    }
    
    protected void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
        ...

    }
       
    
    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        ILogger logger = _serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger>()!;
        ...
    
        startupForm.Show();
    
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

So my question is, why am I getting null for the services object?  I know I make a mistake somewhere, could someone please point it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create a `ServiceCollection` object separately because it is created and initialised when the host is created.

`IHost` has [`Services`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihost.services) property that contains the program's configured services.

Also you have to change a type for `_serviceProvider` from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider` to its abstraction `System.IServiceProvider`:

```
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

public App()
{
    AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
        .Build();

    _serviceProvider = AppHost.Services;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vadim.  However, it errors out in design time:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IServiceProvider' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) ...

Comment: @Mike oh of course, I didn't see that little thing right away. Just change a type of `_serviceProvider` to `IServiceProvider`

Comment: Sorry, Vadim.  You were right the first time.  I overlooked the fact that you had also mentioned that need to change **_serviceProvider from Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider to its abstraction System.IServiceProvider**.  My bad.  It totally works right now.  Thanks a lot!  This is my first ever question here on this site and your willingness to help a stranger like me is much appreciated.  Thanks again